# Change value in multple rows without using IN

Tags: sql, sql-update, rows

A table has a column with same value over multiple rows.
I want to change this value to another value.

The rows in the column named `regex` that have a specific value e.g. `^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$` need to be changed to `NULL`.

#### What I tried

The following statement works but would be really time consuming because I have to write each row's ID.

```sql
UPDATE Country
SET regex = NULL
WHERE ID IN ('1','2','3')
```

Is there a better (faster) way to change the values without using `IN` predicate with a predefined list?

Comment: It can be `UPDATE Country
SET regex= NULL
WHERE regex = 'some old value'`

Comment: Try `WHERE regex = '^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$'` to select rows that have this value.